# Trying to create google calendar based on a condition

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I will be glad if someone can help out with my request.
I was able to write a working code which creates calendar event but want this to only run if `Column B` is not empty and `Column K` is empty. After the code runs I want the corresponding cell in `Column K` to change to "Scheduled" to prevent duplicate of events.

Here is the code:

```js
function Assignee1() {
/* for order of material */
  
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var ss = sheet.getSheetByName('Order of Material');
    var setup = sheet.getSheetByName('Setup');
    var Id = setup.getRange('H4').getValue();
    var calenderId = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(Id);
    var schedule = ss.getDataRange().getValues();

    schedule.splice(0,3);
    schedule.forEach(function(entry){
      calenderId.createEvent(entry[3], entry[1], entry[2]);
    });

};
```

[Example of a calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMfpT.png)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
function Assignee1() {

  const Spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const Sheet = Spreadsheet.getSheetByName(`Order of Material`)
  const Setup = Spreadsheet.getSheetByName(`Setup`)

  const calendarId = Setup.getRange(`H4`).getValue()
  const Calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId)

  Sheet.getDataRange()
       .getValues()
       .forEach((row, index) => {

         if (row[1].length && !row[10].length) {
           
           const [startTime, endTime, title] = row.slice(0, 3)
           Calendar.createEvent(title, startTime, endTime)
           Sheet.getRange(index+1, 11).setValue(`Scheduled`)

         }

       })

}
```

Additionally, if you plan to be scheduling more than just a few events, consider setting the values all at once:

```
function Assignee1() {

  const Spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const Sheet = Spreadsheet.getSheetByName(`Order of Material`)
  const Setup = Spreadsheet.getSheetByName(`Setup`)

  const calendarId = Setup.getRange(`H4`).getValue()
  const Calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId)

  const eventStatus = Sheet.getDataRange()
                           .offset(1, 0)
                           .getValues()
                           .map(row => { 

                             if (row[1].length && !row[10].length) {

                               const [startTime, endTime, title] = row.slice(0, 3)
                               Calendar.createEvent(title, startTime, endTime)
                               return [`Scheduled`]

                             } else return [row[10]]

                           })

  Sheet.getRange(2, 11, eventStatus.length)
       .setValues(eventStatus)

}
```